# How to do a x-www-form-urlencoded POST login using cypress?

Tags: javascript, request, cypress

I'm trying to build a direct API login using cypress. The app I want to test uses nextAuthJS ([REST docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#post-apiauthsigninprovider))

With postman I checked successfully the login POST request with this body as *x-www-form-urlencoded*:

```
username: 'user'
password: 'pass'
csrfToken: token // <= I recieved the token from `/api/auth/csrf` as a simple GET request.
```

And this is working, as `next-auth.session-token` cookie is created.

Now in my cypress test I tried to build up the same thing:

```
cy.request('/api/auth/csrf').then(({ body: { csrfToken } }) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/auth/callback/credentials',
    form: true,
    body: {
      username,
      password,
      csrfToken
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  })
})
```

As you can see, I first do a GET request to recieve the csrf token. Then I use it in the post request, but I don't get the session cookie in case of an successful login.

I'm not quite sure, if it is correct to use two nested `then()` and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as the postman request is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the new created cookie instead for the request result.

This is the working solution for an API login in cypress using nextAuthJS:

```
cy.request('/api/auth/csrf').then(({ body: { csrfToken } }) => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/auth/callback/credentials',
      form: true,
      body: {
        username,
        password,
        csrfToken
      }
    }).then(() => {
      cy.getCookie('next-auth.session-token').should('exist')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The token is returned as a cookie, do you need to add it to the header?

```js
const username = 'user'
const password = 'pass'

cy.request('/api/auth/csrf')
.then(({ body: { csrfToken } }) => {

   cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/auth/callback/credentials',
    form: true,
    headers: {
      'Cookie': `sessionCookie=${csrfToken}`, 
      // or
      'Cookie': `X-CSRF-Token=${csrfToken}`
    },
    body: {
      username,
      password,
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  })
})
```

Comment: No, the GET request is just `/api/auth/csrf` without any parameters. It returns the token, which is necessary for the POST request. I checked this twice...

Comment: Yes, I saw that from the docs just now. It returns a cookie, so do you need to set it in the header rather than the body (in `/api/auth/callback/credentials`)?